# Display <New> in case of defaulting only Numbers in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

For now I have following requirement: make auto number input field, which can have only numbers, but during initial input should have also display . While implementing this requirement I noticed the following: for only numbers I can use as input mask either '0', '9' or '#', and not 'C'. But when I use '0', '9' or '#' I can't display  in that field. But when I use 'C' as input mask, I give possibility to enter non numeric symbols as well. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PXFieldState class encapsulate the input mask. FieldSelecting event handler is a good place to dynamically set the input mask. You could copy AutoNumberAttribute class and modify it to suit your needs by dynamically setting the input mask in it's FieldSelecting event handler like this:

```
void IPXFieldSelectingSubscriber.FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if (_AttributeLevel == PXAttributeLevel.Item || e.IsAltered)
    {
        string inputMask = e.ReturnValue == null || (e.ReturnValue is string && ((string)e.ReturnValue) == "<NEW>") ? "CCCCCCCC" : "########";
        e.ReturnState = PXStringState.CreateInstance(e.ReturnState, null, null, _FieldName, null, -1, inputMask, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```